# Multiple left joins in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So, i have this query right here:

```
$query1 = 'SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone, matching.date, matching.points, matching.time, matching.epos_id,rbpos_epos.epos_id,rbpos_epos.location
FROM users LEFT JOIN matching WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
AND users.user_id=matching.user_id
LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos WHERE rbpos_epos.epos_id=matching.epos_id';
```

Which is giving me an error, what i'm trying to do in this last line:

```
 LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos WHERE rbpos_epos.epos_id=matching.epos_id';
```

is to get the location for that specific epos_id.

It means , in the matching table, i have a epos_id column, and in the rbpos_epos column i have an epos_id field which beside has a location field.. i need to get the respective location for each epos_id..

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks..

This one works

```
$query1 = 'SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone, matching.date, matching.points, matching.time,matching.location
FROM users ,matching WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
AND users.user_id=matching.user_id';
```

I need to get the location from rbpos_epos table. The two tables rbpos_epos and matching have both a epos_id field

So what i need is to find the location in rbpos_epos based on the epos_id i have at matching..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone, matching.date, matching.points, matching.time, matching.epos_id,rbpos_epos.epos_id,rbpos_epos.location
FROM users 
INNER JOIN matching ON  users.user_id=matching.user_id
INNER JOIN rbpos_epos ON rbpos_epos.epos_id=matching.epos_id
WHERE users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
```

Comment: Look the syntactical error was removed, now the desired output what you want, is a different question though..
So what exactly you want to return?

Comment: Yes, you're right..
So what i need is, i have the users table, which has an user_id , i need to get those fields above from matching table which correspond to this user.

I'm updating my question to what works for me

Comment: Then why dont you try the `INNER JOIN` rather than the left join

Comment: Well, i would if i knew how to, i really am not clear with their difference, this one worked for me and i got stucked in this, now that i need to change it i don't know how

Comment: Have edited my answer using the INNER JOIN, please check if you get the desired rows

Comment: Hmm this time i get empty line...
Ahm, maybe is the Where clause at the end, it shouldn't be there..
i guess!

Comment: Yes, If you replace the Userid in  the where clause, which is having its record in the other two table, you will definately get what you want

Comment: Sorry, can i please bother you again, in coding what does this mean? what do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ON` instead of `WHERE` in your `LEFT JOIN`:

```
$query1 = 'SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone, matching.date, matching.points, matching.time, matching.epos_id,rbpos_epos.epos_id,rbpos_epos.location
FROM users LEFT JOIN matching ON users.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
AND users.user_id=matching.user_id
LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos ON rbpos_epos.epos_id=matching.epos_id';
```

And put any `WHERE` clauses after the `LEFT JOIN`s